# Java InputStream read locale dependent?

Tags: java, utf-8, inputstream

I have client-server application. The client (a C++ application) is sending UTF8 encoded string and the server (a Java application) is reading those strings through socket-port communication. I am facing issues while reading the string on server side in case the server is hosted on Windows OS with locale CP-1252.

Here is pseudo-code

```
private transient Socket socket = null;
private transient InputStream in = null;
private transient OutputStream out = null;

socket = new Socket(server, port);
out = socket.getOutputStream();
in = socket.getInputStream();
```

Socket and InputStream are initialized in some different function and the actual string is read as shown in function below:

```
ReadString()
{
    byte[] backbytes = new byte[2048];

    {
        if ((c = in.read(backbytes)) > 0) {
            if (debug)
                logger.trace("Read " + c + " bytes");
            total = total + c;
            char[] convertedChar = new char[backbytes.length];
            int[] convertedInt = new int[backbytes.length];
            for(int i=0;i < backbytes.length;i++){
                convertedChar[i] = (char) backbytes[i];
                convertedInt[i] = (int) backbytes[i];
            }

            logFilePrint.print("Read string as : " + new String(backbytes, 0, c) + " and the converted char[] of byte[] is : ");
            printArray(logFilePrint, convertedChar);
            logFilePrint.print(" and converted int[] is : " );
            printArray(logFilePrint, convertedInt);
            logFilePrint.flush();

            sb.append(new String(backbytes, 0, c));
        } else {
          break;
        }
    }
}
```

The issue happens for certain Unicode characters such as '私' or 'の'. If I execute the above code for these characters, I get output as

> Read string as : ç§?ã? and the converted char[] of byte[] is : [, ￧,
>   ﾧ, ?, ￣, ?,] and converted int[] is : [, -25, -89, 63, -29, 63, -82,]

However if I change Server encoding by setting JVM's charset to UTF8 using "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 ", I get output as :

> Read string as : 私の and the converted char[] of byte[] is : [, ￧, ﾧ,
>   ﾁ, ￣, ﾁ, ﾮ] and converted int[] is : [, -25, -89, -127, -29, -127, -82,]

The issue in non-UTF8 mode appears to be for characters with byte '0x81'. Foe e.g. character '私' has UTF-8 encoding '0xE7 0xA7 0x81' and 'の' has UTF-8 encoding '0xE3 0x81 0xAE'

As far as I understand, InputStream "in.read(backbytes)" is simply reading the bytes of data sent. Why should the read bytes be affected in case of JVM charset being UTF-8 and non-UTF8? Is the function 'read' locale dependent?

Comment: This has nothing to do with input stream. It has to do how your own code decodes the bytes to strings.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Hi Mark, thanks for you comment! Please refer the reply below for my clarification.

Comment: Impossible to tell without a real [mcve]. Maybe your C++ application actually sends that, maybe there has been a similar conversion issue earlier, maybe the C++ application is echoing back incorrectly encoded data, maybe it is caused by your code ignoring the return value of `in.read(backbytes)` and assuming the full buffer was populated. There is not enough to go on. However the problem with your strings was due to incorrect use of the encodings.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel you were right, the Server side Java application is indeed reading the stream of bytes correctly. It is resend over the port again in the server itself and read again. Also there too many function calls on the server which can potentially be affected if the encoding is not explicitly stated. All the code now needs to be reviewed :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor you chose, [`String(byte[] encoded, int offset, int length)`,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-int-int-) uses the default platform encoding to convert bytes to characters. It explicitly depends on the environment in which it runs.

This is a bad choice for portable code. For network applications, explicitly specify the encoding to be used. You can negotiate this as part of the network protocol, or specify a useful default like UTF-8.

There are a variety of APIs that encode and decode text. For example, the String constructor [`String(byte[] encoded, int offset, int length, Charset encoding)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-int-int-java.nio.charset.Charset-) can be used like this:

```
String str = new String(backbytes, 0, c, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! As you can see in the attached code, I am 'casting' the read bytes to an Integer in the for loop. '**convertedInt[i] = (int) backbytes[i];}**'. So there is no String conversion involved here. Still the int value of the char '?' is modified in case JVM uses default charset (-25, -89, **63**) vs JVM using UTF8 charset (-25, -89,**-127**). There is no String conversion coming in picture here. I am just printing the Integer value of the byte read through InputStream.read() function.

Comment: @user3406792 Yes, I see that, but that's only going to work if the bytes are in the US-ASCII range (0-127). Casting a `byte` that has its most significant bit set (in other words, is a negative value) to a `char` will first perform a unary promotion to an `int` value of 0xFFFFFFxx, then truncate it to 16 bits, 0xFFxx, to fit in a `char`. Further, if the encoded bytes are UTF-8 encoded text, you need a decoder that can interpret the multi-byte sequences to individual characters; this manipulates bits from each byte and can't be done with simple casts.

Comment: @user3406792 I wrote the above in response to your previous comment, so it doesn't really address your new comment, but it's still true: in general, you can't convert a `byte` to a `char` by casting. The reason you see `?` (code 63, decimal) is that the default encoding on the server can't map those values to a character. I'm guessing that, on the server, you have UTF-8 encoded data in a file, that you decode (with the wrong character set), then encode back to bytes and send over the socket. In the original decoding, un-mapped characters are replaced with `'?'`

Comment: I understand your explanation of casting a byte to a char and the subsequent '?' seen in the char that is printed. **But why casting a byte to int should have the same issue.** I am reading same byte data (e.g. binary form 1000 0001) over a port. Now, I am casting this byte to int and printing the int value not char value. So, irrespective of the charset of the JVM, this casting should have produced same output. But in my case the output is '-127' if the charset is UTF8 and '63' for default charset. Only variable is charset used by JVM.

Comment: @user3406792 Yes, convening a byte to a (signed) `int` isn’t a problem. You are seeing the correct results for what was sent through the stream. In that case, as I said before, the server is sending the wrong byte, 63, instead of -127, because somewhere, it’s converting UTF-8 encoded bytes to a string using the wrong decoder. At that point, 0x81 doesn’t have a defined character in that set, so it’s replaced with `'?'`, that encoding’s "replacement character”. Use the constructor I show above with UTF-8 on the server and the client so they match.

Comment: Accepted as answer, as this is the actual solution. The source of confusion was because  there are too many function calls on the server which can potentially affect the string while reading and writing, if the encoding (in-case of non-default encoding)  is not explicitly stated. All the server-side code now needs to be reviewed to check this  :).